# Is there a way to programmatically double tap the overview button?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Is there a way to programmatically double tap the overview button? I want to return to my previously open app when I click an onscreen button I made.

Currently this returns me to previous activity but I want to return to previous app and I know if you double tap the overview button it has the desired effect.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     SomeActivity.this.finish();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`finishAffinity(getActivity());`